# Rename value in column via batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a tab delimited txt file and I am trying to find the value 0 in the last column in every line then rename that value from 0 to K.This is the code I have come up with so far but I can't get the values to change. What am I doing wrong here?

```
ECHO ON
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=E:\psexport"
SET "destdir=E:\psexport"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\nk3.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\nk4.txt"
(
 FOR /f * IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=*"
 SET "line=!line:0=K"
 ECHO !line!
)
)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You are using bang where I would expect to see percentage. Also, I'm not sure about that second set statement.

See my code example below. In the echo command I am calling line, with the variable substitution of replace 0 with K. It's wrapped in percentages because that whole expression is the variable we want to echo.

```
ECHO ON
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=E:\psexport"
SET "destdir=E:\psexport"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\nk3.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\nk4.txt"
(
 FOR /f * IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=*"
 ECHO %line:0=K%
)
)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=E:\psexport"
SET "destdir=E:\psexport"

SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\nk3.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\nk4.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 IF "!line:~-2!"==" 0" (
  ECHO !line:~0,-2! K
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO %%a
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"
GOTO :EOF
```

The `for` syntax requires a `metavariable` - I've used `%%a` - which is alphabetical and case-sensitive.

The modifier `usebackq` is used because the name of the file being read is quoted.

`delims=` means no delimiters, so the entire file line is delivered to `%%a`.

To use substringing, we need to transfer the value to a standard environment variable, then test that the last two characters of the line read are `0`  so that `10` does not get modified. If the test is true, `echo` the line from the beginning (character 0) through to the end **- 2** characters and append `K`, otherwise, regurgitate the original line.

The `set` syntax you were using replaces *every* `0` with `K`.

Comment: Magoo, I have been playing around with what you did but all it is doing is copying everything over to the new file and not changing anything. Within the file, the last value of every line always ends in 0-8.

Comment: It's still not clearhow your data is formatted as you've not supplied a sample. You say to change `0` to `K` if the last *column*  is `0` which implies that the data format is a series of columns separated by some separator character, but you haven't specified that separator. I assumed <space> but perhaps it's <comma> or <tab> If so, change the space in `" 0"` to the separator character you are using.  If you mean where the last **character** on the line is `0` then change `" 0"` to `"0"` and change every `-2` to `-1` (2 places)

Comment: Thank you so very much, Magoo. It is all working now.